# Eclipse hotkey in all views

Tags: java, eclipse, hotkeys

I am trying to setup an hotkey in Eclipse Luna. How can I enable my hotkey combination in all views?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the command scope **In Windows**

[image]